# probability of a sequence of event and their intersection with a an event whose liminf has probabilty 1

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, ratio

Let $P_n=\times_{i=1}^n P$ denote a sequence of product probability measures and $E_n$ a sequence of measurable events such that $P_\infty(\liminf_{n\to \infty}E_n)=1$. Can we conclude that for any other sequence or measurable events $S_n$ we have
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{P_n(E_n \cap S_n)}{P_n(S_n)}=1
$$ 
or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be a counter-example? Apologies if I misunderstood the question.

- $\forall n: E_n \cap S_n = \emptyset$ so the numerator is always $0$.
- $\forall n: P_n(S_n) > 0$ so the denominator is always positive.
- $\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n(S_n) = 0$

I am not exactly sure how to interpret $P_\infty (\lim \inf_{n \to \infty} E_n) = 1$ but the last bullet above should hopefully make it possible...?  Anyway, if all $3$ bullets can be satisfied then the ratio is always $0$ and its limit is also $0$.

Comment: Well, if $P$ has support in $\mathbb{R}$ and $P_\infty$ denotes the associated infinite product law, you could think of $E_n$ as an event of the form $\{|T_n -\theta|<\epsilon\}$, where $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $T_n=f_n(X_1, \ldots,X_n)$, for a function sequence $f_n$ and $X_1,X_2,...$ independent and identically distributed according to $P$. In this case, you could interpret $P_\infty(\liminf_{n\to \infty}E_n)=1$ as $P_\infty(\theta-\epsilon<\liminf_{n\to \infty}T_n , \limsup_{n\to \infty}T_n<\theta+\epsilon)=1$.

Comment: oh sure, for a sequence of real numbers (like $T_n$) the meaning of $\lim \inf$ is standard.  I just wasn't sure what you meant by $\lim \inf E_n$ since $E_n$ is a sequence of _events_, not a sequence of reals.  Anyway, I'm glad my counter-example is general enough to work for your $T_n$.